# How can i make f(a,b,c) = \$A \cdot B \cdot \overline C + A \cdot \overline B\cdot C\$ using only XORs and NANDs?

Tags: integrated-circuit, boolean-algebra, nand

i have this problem where i need to make the Logical Function represented by :

f(A,B,C)= \$A \cdot B \cdot \overline C + A \cdot \overline B\cdot C\ \$ using only XORs and NANDs

The function was as the beginning a 4 Variables Function

$$F(A,B,C,D)= (A \cdot B\cdot \overline C \cdot D + A\cdot \overline B \cdot C + A\cdot B\cdot \overline C \cdot \overline D)$$

And i simplified it by a simple factorisation of \$A \cdot B \cdot \overline C\$ and now i'm stuck,don't know how to make it out of XORs and NANDs.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Do you know how to make it out of just NANDs?

Comment: No....i'm really new to all of this and it's just been a month since i started studying this :)

Comment: An XOR leads to a pattern you want to "look for." This pattern is \$A\:\overline{B} + \overline{A}\:B\$. Separately, you also should look for common factors. Sometimes, that leads to an idea. If you look over your simplified version, I think you will see an "xor" pattern in it and you will also see a common factor, as well. Can you look to see if you can find these? Are you aware of factoring and distribution rules in logic?

Comment: Yes i studied factoring and distribution rules,i'll take another look see if i can find something new ! thanks !

Comment: I think i found something Y=A.(B+C),the + here is circled,the one for the XOR,is this right  ?

Comment: @YahyaSef Good to see that you were able to find things yourself!! Best wishes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A.B.C' + A.B'C = A.(B.C' + B'C)=A.(B.C' + B'C)={[A.(B.C' + B'C)]'}'

B.C' + B'C --> This is the XOR,

[A.(B.C' + B'C)]' --> This is the NAND gate,

{[A.(B.C' + B'C)]'}' --> This is the output of NAND gate negated by a NOR implemented in NAND-2.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope it is clear.